# How do I return Schematron validation results in a structured manner

Tags: xml, schematron

I have created several Schematron assertations and they are all running fine against my XML instances. However, I would like to structure the output of my error messages in such a way, that I later can post-process them, with e.g., Java.

The output of my assertion error message should be

```
<error>
  <errorMessage>My error message</errorMessage>
  <violatingElement>The violating element</violatingElement>
</error>
```

However, a construct such as:

```
<pattern>
  <rule context="/p1:Document/p1:Delivery/p1:DeliveryDetails/p1:ShippingDate">
    <report test=".">
      <error>
       <errorMessage>My error message</errorMessage>
       <violatingElement>The violating element</violatingElement>
      </error>
    </report>
 </rule>
</pattern>
```

does not work. What is the correct way of returning Schematron results in a structured (XML-ified) manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to get a Schematron report as XML you should use SVRL. You can learn more about it here: [Schematron Validation Report Language (SVRL)](http://www.schematron.com/validators.html)

The big advantage of using SVRL is that you can also get detailed information about where the assertion/report was triggered as an XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Schematron by design wants to keep the content of assertions and reports as natural language only. The Standard (available [here](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html)) encourages the use of the diagnostics element for richer information. It states:

> The natural-language assertion may
>   contain information about actual
>   values in addition to expected values
>   and may contain diagnostic
>   information. Users should note,
>   however, that the diagnostic element
>   is provided for such information to
>   encourage clear statement of the
>   natural-language assertion.

diagnostic messages are contained in <diagonstic> elements (wrapped in a <diagnostics> wrapper) and associated with reports and assertions using an ID/IDREF mechanism.

There is an example showing the use of diagnostics in Annex G of the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage a native schematron engine, rather than an XSL stylesheet, to deteremine whether the assertions are satisfied. I'm working with one for .NET / C# [here](https://github.com/gap777/SchemaTron).