# How to display error messages inside shematron file, during validation

Tags: xml-validation, schematron

I'm trying to validate my xml file with a schematron file that have (sch) extension. But I can't receive 
and display the error messages that has placed between `<assert test=...</assert>` tags, inside my schematron file. Could you help please. Thanks a lot.

Here is my validation code block:

```
XmlValidator validator = new XmlValidator();

List<string> message_line = validator.ValidateXmlSchematron(xml_path, sch_file_path);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return Schematron validation results in a structured manner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902349/how-do-i-return-schematron-validation-results-in-a-structured-manner)