# Schematron.net structured error reporting

Tags: c#, xml, schematron

I am using the Schematron.net nuget package and I want to know if it's possible to get the output of a call to Validate to give the results in a structured format that I can then process. My existing solution relies on a try catch block and the assertion failures are all returned as the message within the exception as the error message. Is there a way to get this information as XML? I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902349/how-do-i-return-schematron-validation-results-in-a-structured-manner) which asks a similar question, but the answers don't refer to the Schematron.net implementation.

My code looks like this:

```
try
{
   var bookValidator = new Validator();
   bookValidator.AddSchema("book.xsd");
   bookValidator.Validate("book.xml");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually. I just realised that passing a suitable enumeration of OutputFormatting to the Validator constructor allows me to control the format of the message in the exception, like so:

```
try
{
   //OutputFormatting is a public enum from the Schematron library. Valid values include boolean, default, Log, simple and XML.
   OutputFormatting format = OutputFormatting.XML;
   var bookValidator = new Validator(format);
   bookValidator.AddSchema("book.xsd");
   bookValidator.Validate("book.xml");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //ex.Message will now be in XML format and can be processed however I want!
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

And there's your structured results.  I hope that helps someone as it wasn't obvious to me.